# In a gvNIX application: any way to see only one register in DataTables?

Tags: datatables, spring-roo, gvnix

When I create a DataTables in gvNIX it displays several registers in the table, is there any way to display only one register like the *show* page?

To add the support to DataTables I used the following command:

```
web mvc datatables add --type ~.web.EntityController
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it adding a simple parameter on your roo command.

```
web mvc datatables add --type ~.web.EntityController --mode show
```

As the parameter documentation says *is an optional param that change the Visualization mode: if empty (default) renders a table, otherwise create one-row-per-page + one-cell-per-row datatable will be created. On each cell the content of given mode will be rendered, that is, by setting mode == show, each cell will have the show.jspx containing the data of the current entity.*

Best regards